# Page Management in Blazor

Tags: c#, routes, navigation, blazor

I've looked around but I can't find anything related to managing your pages; by that I mean, everyone seems to just hardcode their page names and navigations to set pages all over the place.

Is this the recommended way of doing it? Just seems like you will have to do a significant amount of refactoring if things change.

If you guys have a setup you really like, I would love to hear about it :)

I've considered making a static lookup class, that can provide all the page paths and their equivalent navigations, but I don't know if it is an absolute overkill.

Comment: This will likely be closed as it asks for opinion.

Comment: You need to define why you think this is wrong, what you want to achieve with an alternative system, and why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection. Remember, each .razor file you create for a Blazor page will have the class generated for it that is the same as the name of the file. You can create a base class called `BasePage` and do `@inherits BasePage` on each of your pages. Then you have a singleton service that uses reflection to find all these classes and keep track of them that way.